# Android ADB - Can't get LG G Pad (VK810) to be recognized

Tags: android, windows, adb

Title says it all. I'm trying to use adb with my tablet, but I can never seem to get it. [I followed this tutorial](http://blog.kikicode.com/2013/10/installing-android-adb-driver-in.html), but all I get is this:

[image]

I don't understand. I tried native LG drivers, followed the aforementioned tutorial, and even just using the device vanilla. Nothing is working, and I don't know why. I manually added my vendor ID to the `adb_usb.ini` if anyone is curious. (LG's VID is 1004).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved my own question after 2 days of working with it. Hopefully this helps anyone in the future.

**Procedure:**

1. Enable developer options on the tablet
2. Enable USB Debugging under `Settings > Developer Options`
3. Go to `Settings > PC Connection > Select USB connection method` and select `Internet connection > Ethernet`
4. [Go here](http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-VK810) and download the USB drivers for whatever OS you need ([Windows Mirror](https://mega.co.nz/#!u48GGJgJ!OKeeFZv8EzRKW-eVlvh3i7WzclkMvPsJtvXYNB65fAA))
5. Install the drivers and connect your device
6. Start adb and check if the device is connected

If for some reason the link in Step 4 ever dies, search for LG G Pad VK810 USB drivers from LG. If you have a different model from a VK810, make sure you use your model.

---

**NOTE:**

As mharr pointed out, you may not be able to find the setting in Step 3 on all devices, but if you have this setting, it is imperative that you set it, otherwise I discovered on my VK810 that adb will not work any other way.

Comment: Thanks, Kenny. Used this to get my LG G Pad 7 (LG410) working. Except I did not need your step 3 (nor could I find that setting).

Comment: Glad this is actually helping people.

Comment: On my LG G Pad 7 (v410) I had to change the `USB PC connection` from notification menu from `Charge tablet` to `Send images PTP` in order to use `adb`

Comment: @FahadAlduraibi thanks, that was the missing secret sauce for me.

Comment: awesome thanks. Silly me thinking a usb device would trigger driver download like most other devices do :) Solved for http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-V410

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same problem with LG V522 tablet.
Only choose the third or fourth option solved the problem.
(photo transfer, or as MIDI devices)

Answer (score 0):

1. Unplug you tablet from the USB Connection
2. Go to Settings -> Developer Options
3. Check the `USB Debugging`
4. Plug the USB Cable